# Resolution of an image in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs. I have an image object. I want the resolution of that image. Image object contains name and image size. How do I do in angularjs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not an angular, but raw javascript solution, if i correctly get what you mean by image resolution.

resolution of your profile image on that page  (firefox console)

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("gravatar-wrapper-32")[0]
// => <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32">
b = a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
// => <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-asvvQTRPD14/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAUM/y73pocx9eq4/photo.jpg?sz=32" alt="" width="32" height="32">
b.width
// => 32
b.height
// => 32
```

Comment: cant we do it in angularjs ??

Comment: i don't know angular, but according to this page (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) you can use it inside your angular code.

Comment: okay will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<img ng-src="{{image.path}}" style="width: {{image.width}}px; height: {{image.height}}px" />
```

And angular code

```
.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.image = {
        path: "",
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    }
     var img = new Image();
     $scope.image.width = img.width;
     $scope.image.height = img.height;
     $scope.image.path = "./image.jpg';// put your image path
    }]);
```

Comment: That's fine. I also removed my replied comments :p

Answer (score 0):

You got image size that is height and width in pixel. Then you calculate the using Following Formula.

**Formula: Pixels ÷ DPI = Inches**

If you know the pixel width and height of an image, this section will calculate the physical size (in inches) of the image when it is printed or displayed on various devices. To use the calculator, enter the width and height, then select the output resolution which will be used.